# Jpa or entity manager deal with list of parameter : List<Long>

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I have tried :

```
@Query("Select m.id from Cars m where m.id not in :x")
List<Long> findNotChoosenCars(@Param("x") List<Long> CarsId);
```

I get :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « ) »
Translation: syntax error near << ) >>
```

I have also tried to put :x in brackets like : (:x)

I have also tried

```
@Query(value = "Select id from Cars where id not in (?1)",nativeQuery = true)
List<Long> findNotChoosenCars(List<Long> CarsId);
```

And also:

```
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;
   private List<Long> getNotSelectedCarsIds(List<Long> selectedIds){

    List<String>strings=selectedIds.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
    final String notSelectedCarIdsSql= "Select id from Car where id not in (:strings)";
    return emf.createEntityManager().createNativeQuery(notSelectedMarkerIdsSql)
            .setParameter("strings",strings)
            .getResultList();
}
```

I still have the same stacktrace. I'm using postgres 9.4 
Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it fails when the list of string is empty.

Try to add a check before the query call.

```
if (strings == null || strings.size() == 0) {
    return new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: You were right. I thought if null the returned value would be null. I didn't expect a fail.. Thank you.